# SQL Server 2008 Install fails error reading etwcls.mof

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I receive the following error when trying to install Sql Server 2008 Standard on a Windows Server 2008 box.

Error reading from file D:\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\PFiles\SqlServr\MSSQL.X\MSSQL\Binn\etwcls.mof.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.

When searching the interwebs I only find information about compiling this file but not reading.

The file exists in the location requested.

I have run the WMIDiag tool and there doesn't seem to be any issues.

I am not sure what else I can do to solve this issue and can't seem to find anything on the internet about it.

Cross posted at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/ae47c277-e822-49c1-89b8-701e23702633

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you installing via CD/DVD? If so, have you already tried copying the contents of the CD/DVD to local disk and installing from there?

Comment: haven't tried that. will do so and post back.

Comment: Trying to copy the DVD to hard drive revealed corruptions in the DVD. Mounted ISO and copied to HDD directly without burning solved the problem.
Thanks