# How do I solve MSSQL 2008 install error, "The MOF compiler could not connect with the WMI server"?

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation

Possibly related to:

- [SQL Server 2008 Install fails error reading etwcls.mof](https://serverfault.com/questions/138547/sql-server-2008-install-fails-error-reading-etwcls-mof)

After [manually removing MSSQL 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955404) from my system (uninstall failed to remove two instances), I receive the following error when trying to re-install:

> The MOF compiler could not connect
>   with the WMI server. This is either
>   because of a semantic error such as an
>   incompatibility with the existing WMI
>   repository or an actual error such as
>   the failure of the WMI server to
>   start.

It seems that mofcomp is failing with one of the .mof files, but I'm not sure which, or why. Digging through the [connect article](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=356258&wa=wsignin1.0) gave some indications, but no solution. I've run `winmgmt /salvagerepository`, which returns "WMI repository is consistent".

Currently, I'm unable to install MSSQL 2008. Please help!

Comment: May not be your case but I've read elsewhere this could be related to the WMI Service not being installed.

Comment: Hmm, WMI service (Winmgmt) is running.

Comment: Grrr Microsoft = sucks. Why am I bothering?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem and fixed it as below:

I downloadeded the portable (executable on any window based computer without installation) "Program Install and Uninstall troubleshooter" (a replacement of Windows Installer Cleanup Utility) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2438651 and executed the Fixit.exe. Have repeated the option named as "Fix problems with programs that can't be installed or uninstalled" to uninstalled the SQL Server 2008 registry entry(ies). After that, I installed the SQL Server 2008 which completed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was caused by the Firewall service.  I had a warning message stating the firewall was enabled.  A review of several internet sites indicated it was an issue so I continued.  The MOF compiler error message did not indicate it had anything to do with the firewall.  I stopped the firewall and reinstalled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Following this guide seems to do something...

- [Repairing and re-registering the WMI](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/repairwmi.htm)

... not sure if it's completely fixed the issue though.

Comment: Hmm, the error still occurs - however the installation continues from this point. I'm not even sure that's because of the above "solution"... Gah!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the installation media.  Assuming that you're using 32-bit for your OS, then under your setup root go into \x86\Setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\PFiles\SqlServr\MSSQL.X\MSSQL\Binn and take a look at that etwcls.mof file using Notepad and see if it looks fully formed like any regular class should.  (Go into \x64\Setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\PFiles\SqlServr\MSSQL.X\MSSQL\Binn if you're using 64-bit) If you get to the bottom and are seeing brackets not being closed, etc. then this is what the problem is.

I still haven't decided what to do about this yet....  If you have the disk or ISO handy try uninstalling/reinstalling using it.

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall your SQL server.

Then download this tool: http://majorgeeks.com/download.php?det=4459
(Microsoft Corp.) Windows Installer Cleanup Utility

WARNING: It is deprecated. However when I ran into this issue before I did not have a problem with it. It will allegedly cleanup your Win Install tool.

After you have ran the tool, try to install again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, but no answers provided in the internet gave me a solution. I re-installed many times. But that did not work. Finally, I changed the instance name from MSSQLSERVER to something else. Then SQL server installed fine. I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error this week and was able to get past it without having to reinstall the OS, which is apparently a feat.

I found this message in the Detail.txt log file:

```
2015-07-23 15:48:39 Slp: Sco: Attempting to install MOF file
2015-07-23 15:48:39 Slp: Running: C:\Windows\system32\WBEM\mofcomp.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"
2015-07-23 15:48:39 Slp: Microsoft (R) MOF Compiler Version 6.0.6000.16386
2015-07-23 15:48:39 Slp: Copyright (c) Microsoft Corp. 1997-2006. All rights reserved.
2015-07-23 15:48:39 Slp: File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof' not found!
2015-07-23 15:48:39 Slp: Sco: Compile operation for mof file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof failed. Exit code 1
```

After that, I uninstalled SQL following the steps outlined here (with the exception of step 8, which is a utility for Windows XP and is deprecated):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sreekarm/archive/2010/03/15/sql-express-is-not-installed-properly-steps-to-be-taken-before-reinstall-again.aspx

After that, I started the install again.  I clicked through all the dialog boxes up until the point that it was about to start the install.  Then, I copied the following two files from a known good SQL installation:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\1033\sqlmgmprovider.mfl
```

After that, I got past the MOF Compiler error in the SQL install.  I did get another error that caused me to have to copy the following files as well:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\RsFxInstall\RsFx0100.inf
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\RsFxInstall\RsFx0101.inf
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\RsFxInstall\RsFx0102.inf
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\RsFxInstall\RsFx0103.inf
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\RsFxInstall\RsFx0104.inf
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\RsFxInstall\RsFx0105.inf
```

I'm not sure if this was related or not, but after doing the clean uninstall, copying all 8 of the files listed above, then re-starting the install, it worked.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: When linking to a resource, please include the information from it that is necessary to fix the issue in case the link goes dead.

Answer (score -2):

Reinstall. First the server, then MSSQL.

Comment: Reinstalling Windows is not an option.

Comment: Then you have no option. THis is an OS level error - and I would NOT have a database server with a broken OS level function around ever.

Comment: It's a dev machine.

Comment: Even more so ;) Obviously the dev did something that damaged the OS partially ;)

Answer (score -2):

in my opinion there are only two reasons of failed installtion of sql server.
First you have a virus infected windows.so first scan windows drive with some best antivirus like 360security or panda global protection etc.
if your windows is not infected by any virus then there is problem of sqlserver
installation setup files.Then get another new copy of sqlserver to install.
And i hope problem will be solved. Thanks Rana Imran